# Electron app runs without any errors however the window does not open or show in task manager

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am building an electron app. The app runs without any errors but does not open. I am running windows 7 on a 32 bit machine. My main.js file looks like this:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
// Initialize window
let win;

function createWindow() {

     win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        icon: __dirnaname+ '/assets/images/icon.jpg'
    });

    // Load Window
    win.loadUrl(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, './index.html'),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
    }));

    // Close window
    win.on('closed', () =>{
        win = null;
    });

    //Run Create Window Function
    win.on('ready', createWindow);

    //Check Mac OS platform
    app.on('all-window-closed', () => {
        if(process.platform !== 'darwin') {
            app.quit();
        }
    });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong

```js
win.on('ready', createWindow);
```

you meant

```js
app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

outside of `createWindow`'s scope. Like this:

```js
function createWindow() {
  ...
};
app.on('all-window-closed', () => {
  ...
});
app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

Comment: I tried it but it throws an error: 'Cannot read porperty 'on' of null'

Comment: `app` should be valid, because your require'd it by `const { app } = require('electron')`

Comment: Thanks for the comments I figured what was the problem. The loadUrl protocol I had omitted : in front of file it should've been protocol: 'file:'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after I upgraded electron from v3.x to v8.x it started working