# Electron Window does not open, and it's not showing any errors - Electron-forge - win10

Tags: ubuntu, electron, deb, electron-forge, debian-packaging

I'm running into exactly same issue. and the solving that are already here does not help me.

```
running on VirtualBox 6.1.28 with Ubuntu 20.04  
electron: v16.0.0  
node: v16.13.0  
npm: v8.1.2
```

I've packaged the app with "electron-forge make" CLI, and installed the .deb file accordingly, and by the time the app should start it does nothing, and gives no errors.

only the packaged app. Dev is working running with "npm start" or "electron ."

Same question here: [Electron Window does not open, but doesn't show any errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56033095/electron-window-does-not-open-but-doesnt-show-any-errors)

Comment: this is the exact same toppic as mine.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56033095/electron-window-does-not-open-but-doesnt-show-any-errors

Comment: Is this only in the packaged app, or also in development?

Comment: only the packaged app. Dev is working running with "npm start" or "electron ."

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more detail; do *not* add multiple comments to provide more details!